# AES_GCM ciphers are not disabling using SHA256 or SHA384

Tags: java, sha256

I am trying to disable ciphers using `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms`.

I have created a properties file named `disabledAlgorithms.properties` and it is has `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=AES_128_CBC,SHA1,SHA256`.

I am passing this property file as
`java -Djava.security.properties=disabledAlgorithms.properties`

Here I have used SHA1 to disable all ciphers containing SHA.

I tried to disable all cipher suites containing SHA256 but the cipher suites with AES_GCM are not disabled.

Ex: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_with_AES_128_GCM_SHA256.
Same thing is seen for SHA384.

Could you please help how to disable all ciphers containing SHA256 and SHA384

Comment: Which Java? On my Oracle 11.0.8 that does disable all ciphersuites using SHA1 or SHA256 as asked; even without AES_128_CBC it does so because all such suites have MAC=SHA1 or SHA256. It doesn't disable suites using SHA384 because you didn't specify SHA384; if I add that, it disables ALL ciphers which means no connections at all can be made. In fact specifying just SHA256,SHA384 disables suites using MAC=SHA1, because all default suites now use SHA256 or SHA384 for 1.2PRF or 1.3HKDF. You can't possibly accomplish anything useful doing this.

Comment: I tried jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SHA256 in disabledAlgorithms.properties file but it failed to disable AES_128_GCM_SHA256 and AES_256_GCM_SHA256 ciphersuites. I need to disable all ciphersuites containing SHA256. Same thing happened with SHA384 also.

Comment: As I said, on Oracle 11.0.8 for me specifying SHA256 does disable all SHA256 suites including AES_128_GCM_SHA256. There are NO AES_256_GCM_SHA256 suites; ALL AES_256_GCM suites use SHA384 -- and are disabled if I disable SHA384, but of course not if I disable only SHA256. Unless you can identify a case that actually fails, I consider this unreproducable and thus unanswerable.

Comment: I am using java 1.8.0_251. Is there any way to disable sha256 ciphers using jdk.tls.disabledAlgoriths=sha256 in disabledAlgorithms.properties file and running java application as    java -Djava.security.properties=disabledAlgorithms.properties .....